# CSOM Looking for a list of Columns / Fields that show up on SharePoint Form

Tags: c#, sharepoint, properties, content-type, csom

I would like to get a list of Fields of a content type.  I am hoping to get a list of just the fields that show up on the Edit Form or Edit Properties of an uploaded document.

Below code will get me the fields list, but I cannot distinguish what fields are just shown on the Edit Form / Display Form.

I think I need to look at FieldLink Collection as that should have a ShowInForm property.   But that "ShowInForm" was not a valid property in that collection.

I also did some googling but I can see how to setShowInForm, but not how to get that value for the field.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(site);

```
        //// Get the content type using ID: 0x01003D7B5A54BF843D4381F54AB9D229F98A - is the ID of the "Custom" content Type
        string contentTypeID = GetContentTypeGUID(contentType, site);
            ContentType ct = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById(contentTypeID);

            //// Gets a value that specifies the collection of fields for the content type
            FieldCollection fieldColl = ct.Fields;
            clientContext.Load(fieldColl);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //// Display the field name

            foreach (Field oField in fieldColl)
            {
               // Code for each Field
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Per mt test, the value of ShowInForm is in the field.SchemaXml property.

[image]

Comment: I do not have that property in my field.SchemaXml.  I am on SharePoint 2013.  
 
 Here is what I do have:

 <Field ID=\"{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}\" Name=\"FileLeafRef\" SourceID=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3\" StaticName=\"FileLeafRef\" Group=\"_Hidden\" ShowInFileDlg=\"FALSE\" ShowInVersionHistory=\"FALSE\" Type=\"File\" DisplayName=\"Name\" AuthoringInfo=\"(for use in forms)\" List=\"Docs\" FieldRef=\"ID\" ShowField=\"LeafName\" JoinColName=\"DoclibRowId\" JoinRowOrdinal=\"0\" JoinType=\"INNER\" Required=\"TRUE\" Customization=\"\" />"